In MathJax, is there a way to know the equation current location in the DOM?
I want to have chapters in the equation numbering, using elements present in the DOM.
I encountered this example:
MathJax = {
  section: 1,
  tex: {
    tagformat: {
      number: (n) => MathJax.config.section + '.' + n,
    }
  },
  startup: {
    ready() {
      const Configuration = MathJax._.input.tex.Configuration.Configuration;
      const CommandMap = MathJax._.input.tex.SymbolMap.CommandMap;
      new CommandMap('sections', {
        nextSection: 'NextSection',
        setSection: 'SetSection',
      }, {
        NextSection(parser, name) {
          MathJax.config.section++;
          parser.tags.counter = parser.tags.allCounter = 0;
        },
        SetSection(parser, name) {
          const n = parser.GetArgument(name);
          MathJax.config.section = parseInt(n);
        }
      });
      Configuration.create(
        'sections', {handler: {macro: ['sections']}}
      );
      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
    }
  }
};

But this needs to use a <span style="display: hidden">\(\nextSection\)</span> in order to increment the section number.
In the DOM I could do something like
const chapterNumber = document.querySelector(
  "#quarto-sidebar a.sidebar-link.active span.chapter-number"
).textContent;

But that breaks when there is more than one chapter, if I had the current location of the equation, this issue could be solved.
